# Do we have a option to implement Keyboard shortcuts for React routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Consider i have a following routes in reactjs.

```
<NavLink to="/home">Home</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/about">About</NavLink>
<NavLink to="/contactus">Contact Us</NavLink>
```

I would like to implement keyboard shortcuts to these routes. For example if i click on **H** in the keyboard then it should route to Home.
How to implement this with hotkey components.

Answer (score -1):

**you can use onkeypress event listener on document.**

```
eventTarget.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
  if (event.isComposing || event.keyCode === 229) {
    return;
  }
  // do something
});
```

you can search for key code of every key [here](https://keycode.info/)

Comment: can this be achieved by using any react components?